# Automorphism of semisimple algebraic group of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I have the following problem and would be grateful if somebody could point me to a reference or give a brief explanation:

> I have a semisimple algebraic group $G$ (you can assume in
>   characteristic 0 over an algebraically closed field or even
>   $\mathbb{C}$ if it helps) and a automorphism $\sigma:G\to G$ of order
>   2. Denote with $H$ the subgroup of $G$ fixed by $\sigma$ and let $N(H)$ be it's normalizer in $G$.
>
> The paper that I'm reading makes the following claim:
>
> The subgroup $K$ of $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ generated by $Ad(N(H))$ and
>   $d\sigma$ is reductive.

They assume that it's obvious that $Ad(N(H))$ is reductive and now since $Ad(N(H))$ has at most index 2 in $K$ we have that $K$ is reductive. Both statements are not quite clear to me right now and I couldn't find anything in the standart literature (I have Borels book and Tauvel/Yu's book on algebraic groups).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be working over $\mathbb{C}$.

First we look at the lie algebra of $H$, call it $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g} := Lie(G)$. One knows by assumption that $\mathfrak{h}$ is the fixed point of $d\sigma$. Also it is a fact that one can find a cartan involution of $\mathfrak{g}$ say $\theta$ which commutes with $d\sigma$. Thus an easy computation shows that $\mathfrak{h}$ is stable under $\theta$. This implies that $\mathfrak{h}$ is reductive.

This is in turn implies that $\mathfrak{h} = [\mathfrak{h}, \mathfrak{h}] \oplus \mathfrak{z}$ where $\mathfrak{z}$ consists of semisimple endormorphism under any embedding of $\mathfrak{h}$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$. From here it follows that $R_u(H) = 0$ otherwise we would have obtained some nilpotent ideal in $\mathfrak{h}$ which clearly doesnot exists. Hence $H^0$ is reductive and thus equivalently $H$ is reductive.(look at lemma 3.1 in the paper titled "Fully reducible subgroups" by G.D.Mostow here we use the fact that in char 0 a group is reductive iff it is fully reducible.)

Now one one knows that connected componenet of the normalizer of a connected reductive group is reductive and hence $N_G(H^0)^0$ is reductive and thus $N_G(H^0)$ is reductive (look at this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114243/is-the-normalizer-of-a-reductive-subgroup-reductive). But $N_G(H^0) \supset N_G(H)$, and clearly $N_G(H^0) \supset H$ and hence $N_G(H^0) \subset N_G(N_G(H^0)) \subset N_G(H)$. Hence $N_G(H) = N_G(H^0)$ is reductive.

Now $(Ad(N_G(H^0))^0 = Ad(N_G(H^0)^0)$ and we know(corollary 14.11 in Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups) that image of a reductive group is reductive and hence $Ad(N_G(H))^0$ is reductive and thus $Ad(N_G(H))$ is reductive.

Note that $K^0 = Ad(N_G(H))^0$(as $Ad(N_G(H))$ is of finite index in $K$) which was reductive and hence $K$ is reductive.